# Why isn't CMD or Powershell accepting hotkeys with 'Alt' in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm using pyautogui to open the menu opened by pressing 'Alt + Space'. When I run the code on Jupyter notebook, it works as expected, but not when I run it on either CMD or Powershell. Why?

I've tried using the keyUp and keyDown functions to simulate the hotkey function, but it doesn't work. Other hotkeys such as 'Win + d' work on CMD. But hotkeys using 'Alt', 'Altleft' and 'Altright' don't work.

```
import pyautogui
import time

#time.sleep(1.0)
pyautogui.hotkey('altleft', 'space', interval=0.2)
```

Comment: How are you ensuring that Jupyter has the focus when the hotkeys are used? Or that a CMD or PowerShell instance has the focus?

Comment: @ Andy G I am not. Would not focus have been an issue for non-'Alt' keys as well in CMD or Powershell?

Comment: Focus is always an issue when sending keys. It could even be that an application has focus, but that focus is not in the main window; it might be, for example, on a menu. In which case, Alt may have the opposite of the desired effect. I don't know whether this is the case here, but focus could be. One way to test is to send a couple of text characters and see if, or where, they appear.

Comment: Characters do appear. One thing I observed is that if I'm using the 'Alt + space' hotkey, CMD seems to ignore Alt. And space is entered.  Same with others hotkeys like 'Alt + enter'. I see a new line in CMD due to the enter.

Comment: I am not sure about the behaviour. What option will you then select from the control menu? Try including it with the hotkey, or immediately after. Try 'alt' rather than 'altleft'. Good luck.

Comment: I would even try alt + alt + space. Sending keystrokes successfully can require experimentation to discover where you are and what is active.

Comment: Neither alt + space nor alt + alt + space is working. I'm trying to automate minimizing the active window.

Comment: As mentioned, try alt + space + n to perform the minimizing straightaway, rather than trying to hold the control menu open/ poised.

Comment: Still no luck. alt  + space + n prints "space + n" on the prompt.